# Can you remove 'description' from facebook feed dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, customization, feed

I'm using, but not married to, the feed dialog to share to a users wall on facebook.

```
var obj = {
method: 'feed',
to: shareTarget,
from: shareTarget,
link: 'myLink.html',
picture: 'myPic.jpg',
name: 'auto populated if left blank',
caption:'also auto populated if left blank',
description:'again, also auto populated if left blank'
};

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

The feed dialog contains/displays several params which I would prefer not display. However, when I remove the 'description' or 'caption' field from the above code they still appear in the feed dialog, displaying auto-generated copy such as 'apps.facebook.com'.

I've shared items to walls that do not contain these fields but can't figure out how it's done.

For example, this polling app will display only the few fields it needs with no description or caption (https://apps.facebook.com/my-polls/).

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: specify the description & leave it empty, as simple as that! 
`description:''`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found that putting a space in the description field instead of leaving it blank worked.